# How to get Folder stats to a csv file for a specific year (like 2022)

Tags: powershell

This script runs fine but I don't know how to add something like   to get just 2022 last edited files only like   `{where LastWriteTime -eq 2022}`

```
$arr = @()
gci 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\' -recurse  | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} | % {
  $obj = New-Object PSObject
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $_.DirectoryName
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Name
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Length $_.Length
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty CreationTime $_.CreationTime
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Access $_.LastAccessTime
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Owner ((Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner)
  $arr += $obj
  }
  $arr | Export-CSV -notypeinformation "C:\Users\myusername\Downloads\report.csv"
```

Comment: I assume you meant "how to get the files stats" instead of folders because of  `? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LastWriteTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime?view=net-7.0#system-io-filesysteminfo-lastwritetime) is a [`DateTime` instance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0), hence you can simply check the [`Year` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.year?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-year) and compare against it. As for your code, 3 recommendations:

1. Use [`-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2#-file) or [`-Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2#-directory) when needing to filter by any of them.
2. Use [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2) to instantiate your objects. It's easier and faster.
3. [Avoid adding elements `+=` to a fixed collection `@()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708578/why-should-i-avoid-using-the-increase-assignment-operator-to-create-a-colle). You can take full advantage of the pipeline in this case, *get the files one by one, process each object and output them to a file*.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\' -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq 2022) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Directory    = $_.DirectoryName
            Name         = $_.Name
            Length       = $_.Length
            CreationTime = $_.CreationTime
            Access       = $_.LastAccessTime
            Owner        = (Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner
        }
    }
} | Export-CSV "C:\Users\myusername\Downloads\report.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: How do I get the original document Author( not the owner) into this script?

i .e.  Not  Owner        = (Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner   something like: Author = (Get-ACL $_.FullName).Authors

Comment: @KD_Raj there is no reference of the older owner of the in the ACL, if it was changed I dont think you can recover that information

Answer (score 2):

[Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74076161/45375) contains an effective solution and explains the problems with your approach well.

Let me complement it with an alternative solution that uses the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet to perform the desired filtering first, and the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet with [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) to get the desired property names and values to pass to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -File C:\Users\myusername\Documents -recurse  | 
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq 2022 } |
  Select-Object @{ Name='Directory'; Expression = { $_.DirectoryName } },
                Name,
                Length,
                CreationTime,
                @{ Name='Access'; Expression = { $_.LastAccessTime } },
                @{ Name='Owner'; Expression = { (Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner } } |
  Export-CSV -notypeinformation "C:\Users\myusername\Downloads\report.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks despite syntactical differences it seems to avoid using any object instantiation I think.   Interesting.

Comment: @KD_Raj, in this case it is `Select-Object` that creates the `[pscustomobject]` output objects. That is, the specified properties become the properties of a newly constructed `[pscustomobject]`.